# SQL loop and exec query - Must declare the scalar variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have table with columns: [1959], [1960], [1961] ... [2016]

And I have written a query:

```
DECLARE @cnt INT = 1959;

WHILE @cnt < 2017
BEGIN
    DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(1000)

    SET @sql = 'SELECT @cnt as ''Year'', DC.[Code], PT.[Country Name], PT.[@colname] as ''totalGDP'', PG.[@colname] as ''growthGDP''
        FROM [dbo].[GDP] PT
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[GDPgrowth] PG ON PT.[Country Name]=PG.[Country Name]
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[Dictionary] DC ON PT.[Country Name]=DC.[Country]'

    SET @sql = REPLACE(@sql, '@colname', CAST(@cnt AS VARCHAR(255)));

    EXEC(@sql);

    SET @cnt = @cnt + 1;
END;
```

but something is wrong, I get an error:

> Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 7
>   Must declare the scalar variable "@cnt"

What is wrong and how can I fix it?

Comment: Just do the same replace in both places. But the variable outside the dynamic sql isn't available inside. Look up `sp_executesql`.

Comment: You might also just want `unpivot`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass it in as a parameter.  Instead of your `exec()`, use:

```
exec sp_executesql @sql, N'@cnt int', @cnt=@cnt
```